# Using sed, identify the right line in text file and write three different portions to separate variables

Tags: regex, linux, sed, text-processing

I have a group of text files that each contain one instance of the following line somewhere, where the "(MR #" is the best way to identify the right line...

```
Smith, John A (MR # MR123456)
```

I'd like to get three sed statements that, when run against a given file, populate the following three variables: Plname, Pfname and MRnum.  Using the example above, I'd like the variables to end up holding the following after running the sed statements.

```
Plname=Smith
Pfname=John
MRnum=MR123456
```

Despite many sed examples out there, I'm new to this, and currently struggling with the exact syntax.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: If I know that the line in question happens to be the first line of the file, as it often is, I'm able to get the Plname using the following.  But I can't assume that it will always be the first line.

    sed -n '1 s/,.*//p' $VAR_CURRENT_FILENAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$ cat t
bla-bla-bla
Smith, John A (MR # MR123456)
bla-bla-bla
$ Plname="$(sed -n '/(MR #/{s/^\([^,]\+\),.*/\1/p;q}' t)"
$ Pfname="$(sed -n '/(MR #/{s/^[^,]\+,[ ]\?\([^(]\+\).*/\1/p;q}' t)"
$ MRnum="$(sed -n '/(MR #/{s/^[^(]\+(MR # \([^)]\+\).*/\1/p;q}' t)"
$ printf "Plname = %s, Pfname = %s, MRnum = %s\n" "$Plname" "$Pfname" "$MRnum"
Plname = Smith, Pfname = John A , MRnum = MR123456
```

---

Little explanation:

`/(MR #/{s/^\([^,]\+\),.*/\1/p;q}` is a short form of

`/(MR #/                  #1
  {
    s/^\([^,]\+\),.*/\1/; #2
    p;                    #3
    q                     #4
  }`

- `sed` will parse file line by line
- `-n` flag says that `sed` won't print each line (it does it by default), because we will do this manually if needed
- `#1` (`//`) finds line which contains `(MR #`
- and if line matches then we do following actions:

  - `#2` (`s///`) replaces its content by regular expression
  - `#3` (`p`) prints result
  - `#4` (`q`) stops processing of file because we already find what we are looking for

Comment: This is great help and I appreciate it a lot.  What would I do if I wanted to only get John (not: John A) as Pfname?

Comment: You need to change regexp: `sed -n '/(MR #/{s/^[^,]\+,[ ]\?\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/p;q}'` (actually I've changed only one symbol in it). And, by the way, if my answer was useful why are not accept or up vote it? :)